# Build a time out to load the page slower

Tags: php, performance, timeout

Is there a way to make the loading of a page go slower? There are some processes which happen to fast to get a grip on and I would like to see them a bit slower.
Is there anything I can do to **slow down** the loading-time of a page?

I need this because there is one CSS-selector on which I need to change something, but I can't catch him with firebug, cause the page is loading too fast.

Comment: How about some more details, what is going too fast? Why is it a problem? We don't have very much to go on here...

Comment: You can [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) or [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) - but please share some details of the `processes which happen to fast`, usually the goal of serving a page is to do it as fast as possible, if you find yourself needing to slow it down it's probably your program design that is at fault.

Comment: @DaveRandom - I would suspect he's trying to debug something

Comment: @EricPetroeltje that's correct!

Comment: @Michiel If you explain the actual problem you have (in terms of the CSS problem) and the end result you want you will get a much better set of answers, I feel. If you really want to slow the process down you *could* max the CPU on the server with another process (for example run a PHP script of `while (TRUE) continue;`) but this is *not* recommended.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `sleep()` in PHP to make it delay the loading.

Here is an example from the PHP Manual:

```
<?php

// current time
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

// sleep for 10 seconds
sleep(10);

// wake up !
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

?>
```

http://uk.php.net/sleep

Comment: Hm, this is just a delaying of the loading... Can I just load the page slower?

Comment: No, not *really* because that is down the rate at which the sever transfers the data to the client. You *could* use mod_bandwidth in Apache to limit the rate at which data.

Comment: With the `sleep()` function, all process are set on hold for some seconds. But I want to slow down the process. So normally it would take the page 1 second to load, I know want it to be 2. So I have a better visual on what's happening on the page.

Comment: Well you could just output a massive amount of data, but that seems like a bad idea just to slow a page down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sleep(seconds);` (see [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)), but I suspect your application design should be improved if you need it...

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 (seconds based)**

You could use

```
sleep($seconds);
```

where `$seconds`, as the variable name explain, are the seconds that the script have to wait.

**Solution 2 (microseconds based)**

You can also use

```
usleep($microseconds);
```

to delay the execution in microseconds instead of seconds.

**References**

- [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)
- [usleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php)

Answer (score 0):

[`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php).